# get primary key from context ofbiz

Tags: ofbiz

can any one help me pleaze , i have a entity named Person and formateur extend from this entity
so i want to add a formateur the probleme that i need  the id of the table Person how i can get it plz

```
public static Map<String, Object> createFormateur(DispatchContext dctx, Map<String, ? extends Object> context) {
Map<String, Object> result = ServiceUtil.returnSuccess();
Delegator delegator = dctx.getDelegator();
try {
    GenericValue formateurAdd = delegator.makeValue("twFormateur");


    formateurAdd.setString("partyId", context.toString());

    formateurAdd.setNonPKFields(context);
    // Creating record in database for OfbizDemo entity for prepared value
    formateurAdd = delegator.create(formateurAdd);
    result.put("partyId", formateurAdd.getString("partyId"));
    Debug.log("==========Thisis my first Java Service implementation in Apache OFBiz. OfbizDemo record created successfully with ofbizDemoId: "+formateurAdd.getString("partyId"));
} catch (GenericEntityException e) {
    Debug.logError(e, module);
    return ServiceUtil.returnError("Error in creating record in OfbizDemo entity ........" +module);
}
return result;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get a single key from context, partyId for example, you can try :

```
String partyId = (String)context.get("partyId");
```

in this case you probably want to populate all the information of the context into your GenericValue, you can try :

```
GenericValue formateurAdd = delegator.makeValidValue("twFormateur", context);
```

Comment: thanks it work good, i do the same but i forget to do cast  from object to String thanks